# Digital Ocean, how can i secure my SSH connections?

Tags: digital-ocean

I'm new to this online server area, all I've done so far is create a server on Digital Ocean using Ubuntu 20.04 operating system with LAMP library (apache2) installed.

Currently I use Putty to access the server's command line (I use private key ssh authentication files).

When I put the domain URL or IP, enter port 22, and click "Open connection", the application automatically manages to connect to the server asking for login and password.

Pretty simple isn't it? My concern is that anyone who has the least knowledge can come across the gateway to my server, just that he has the login and password to access.

But when I try to connect with putty on sites like stackoverflow.com, google.com, facebook.com and among others, putty doesn't give me the opportunity to type the login.

Knowing this, how do I secure my server so that it can act in the same way as the aforementioned sites?

Answer (score 0):

You could add some sort of VPN and whitelist a select amount of IP addresses able to access your server. This would add an extra layer of security.